# Customizing elevatedButton Flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to make a custom Elevated Button to reuse it in a sign in page where there be 3 or more button.
but i have some problem.
May be can be work but i can't understand how i can set property for borderRadius and why i have an error in onPress proprety.

````
class CustomElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomElevatedButton({
    this.child,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.borderRadius,
    this.onPressed
});
  final child;
  final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? backgroundColor;
  final MaterialStateProperty<BorderRadius?>? borderRadius;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return ElevatedButton(
      child: child,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
      ),
     onPressed: () {},
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Replace your class with this.

```dart
class CustomElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomElevatedButton({
    required this.child,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.border,
    this.onPressed,
  });
  final Widget child;
  final MaterialStateProperty<Color?>? backgroundColor;
  final MaterialStateProperty<OutlinedBorder?>? border;
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
        shape: border ?? MaterialStateProperty.all(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
CustomElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  border: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
  ),
  child: Text('Button'),
)
```

Comment: I think there is a problem in @verride part of code when set shape.
If i pass your code in this section i have an error becouse i set border ?? but after i give a BorderRadius.circular value

 shape: border ?? MaterialStateProperty.all(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),

and i have the same problem about onPressed isn't definied

Comment: @Jonnyfaz Did you run my code? There's no issue in `onPressed` and even `border`.

Comment: About onPress was my mistake sorry. Buy i don't understan why of we have a radius in customButton we can change the vale in the other button.

Comment: @Jonnyfaz I'm sorry I am not able to understand.